# paypal ipn notify_url working correctly but it shows nothing on my return url that is set

Tags: php, oop, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am up and running my E-Commerce website on a server. I use Paypal IPN notifications to send customers with notifications about payments made by them.
I am currently using Paypal sandbox for testing.

I proceed to checkout => paypal developer account => make payment => i receive message in my paypal account as ipn request is sent but i don't get the values of ipn request in my orders table in the database.
What could be the reason for this ?

I have set my IPN details as in the screenshot below.
and 
I also have the screenshot of IPN history of my Paypal developer account.
Can anyone please help me and tell me the reason why the values in my database are not updated ?

Following is my code:

classes/Paypal.php

```
<?php
class PayPal {


    private $_environment = 'sandbox';
    private $_url_production = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    private $_url_sandbox = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    private $_url;
    private $_cmd;
    private $_products = array();
    private $_fields = array();
    private $_business = 'xxx-xxx@gmail.com';
    private $_page_style = 'null';
    private $_return;
    private $_cancel_payment;
    private $_notify_url;
    private $_currency_code = 'GBP';
    public $_tax_cart = 0;  
    public $_tax = 0;
    public $_populate = array();
    private $_ipn_data = array();
    private $_log_file = null;
    private $_ipn_result;



    public function __construct($cmd = '_cart') {

        $this->_url = $this->_environment == 'sandbox' ?
                        $this->_url_sandbox :
                        $this->_url_production;

        $this->_cmd = $cmd;

        $this->_return = SITE_URL."/?page=return";
        $this->_cancel_payment = SITE_URL."/?page=cancel";
        $this->_notify_url = SITE_URL."/?page=ipn";
        $this->_log_file = ROOT_PATH.DS."log".DS."ipn.log";

    }


    public function addProduct($number, $name, $price = 0, $qty = 1) {

        switch($this->_cmd) {

            case '_cart':
            $id = count($this->_products) + 1;
            $this->_products[$id]['item_number_'.$id] = $number;
            $this->_products[$id]['item_name_'.$id] = $name;
            $this->_products[$id]['amount_'.$id] = $price;
            $this->_products[$id]['quantity_'.$id] = $qty;
            break;
            case '_xclick':
            if (empty($this->_products)) {
                $this->_products[0]['item_number'] = $number;
                $this->_products[0]['item_name'] = $name;
                $this->_products[0]['amount'] = $price;
                $this->_products[0]['quantity'] = $qty;
            }
            break;  
        }
    }

    private function addField($name = null, $value = null) {
        if (!empty($name) && !empty($value)) {
            $field  = '<input type="hidden" name="'.$name.'" ';
            $field .= 'value="'.$value.'" />';
            $this->_fields[] = $field;
        }
    }

    private function standardFields() {
        $this->addField('cmd', $this->_cmd);
        $this->addField('business', $this->_business);
        if ($this->_page_style != null) {
            $this->addField('page_style', $this->_page_style);
        }
        $this->addField('return', $this->_return);
        $this->addField('notify_url', $this->_notify_url);
        $this->addField('cancel_payment', $this->_cancel_payment);
        $this->addField('currency_code', $this->_currency_code);
        $this->addField('rm', 2);

        switch($this->_cmd) {
            case '_cart':
            if ($this->_tax_cart != 0) {
                $this->addField('tax_cart', $this->_tax_cart);
            }
            $this->addField('upload', 1);
            break;
            case '_xclick':
            if ($this->_tax != 0) {
                $this->addField('tax', $this->_tax);
            }
            break;
        }   
    }

    private function prePopulate() {
        if (!empty($this->_populate)) {
            foreach($this->_populate as $key => $value) {
                $this->addField($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    private function processFields() {
        $this->standardFields();
        if (!empty($this->_products)) {
            foreach($this->_products as $product) {
                foreach($product as $key => $value) {
                    $this->addField($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->prePopulate();
    }

    private function getFields() {
        $this->processFields();
        if (!empty($this->_fields)) {
            return implode("", $this->_fields);
        }
    }
    private function render() {
        $out  = '<form action="'.$this->_url.'" method="post" id="frm_paypal">';
        $out .= $this->getFields();
        $out .= '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />';
        $out .= '</form>';
        return $out;
    }

    public function run($transaction_id = null) {
        if (!empty($transaction_id)) {
            $this->addField('custom', $transaction_id);
        }
        return $this->render();
    }

    private function validateIpn() {

        $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
            return false;
        }   
            $objForm = new Form();
        $this->_ipn_data = $objForm->getPostArray();

        if (
            !empty($this->_ipn_data) &&
            array_key_exists('receiver_email', $this->_ipn_data) &&
            strtolower($this->_ipn_data['receiver_email']) !=
            strtolower($this->_business)
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;    
    }
    private function getReturnParams() {

        $out = array('cmd=_notify-validate');
        if (!empty($this->_ipn_data)) {
            foreach($this->_ipn_data as $key => $value) {
                $value = function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') ?
                            urlencode(stripslashes($value)) :
                            urlencode($value);
                $out[] = "{$key}={$value}";
            }
        }
        return implode("&", $out);      
    }

    private function sendCurl() {

        $response = $this->getReturnParams();

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
        curl_setopt($ch,    T_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length: " . strlen($response)
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

        $this->_ipn_result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

    }

    public function ipn() {
        if ($this->validateIpn()) {
            $this->sendCurl();
            if (strcmp($this->_ipn_result, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                $objOrder = new Order();

                if (!empty($this->_ipn_data)) {

                    $objOrder->approve(
                        $this->_ipn_data, 
                        $this->_ipn_result
                    );      
                }   
            }       
        }   
    }
}
```

mod/paypal.php

```
<?php
require_once('../inc/autoload.php');
$token2 = Session::getSession('token2');
$objForm = new Form();
$token1 = $objForm->getPost('token');

if ($token2 == Login::string2hash($token1)) {

    // create order
    $objOrder = new Order();
    if ($objOrder->createOrder()) {

        // populate order details
        $order = $objOrder->getOrder();
        $items = $objOrder->getOrderItems();


        if (!empty($order) && !empty($items)) {

            $objBasket = new Basket();
            $objCatalogue = new Catalogue();
            $objPayPal = new PayPal();


            foreach($items as $item) {
                $product = $objCatalogue->getProduct($item['product']);
                $objPayPal->addProduct(
                    $item['product'], 
                    $product['name'], 
                    $item['price'], 
                    $item['qty']
                );
            }


            $objPayPal->_tax_cart = $objBasket->_vat;

            // populate client's details
            $objUser = new User();
            $user = $objUser->getUser($order['client']);

            if (!empty($user)) {


                $objCountry = new Country();
                $country = $objCountry->getCountry($user['country']);


                $objPayPal->_populate = array(
                    'address1'      => $user['address_1'],
                    'address2'      => $user['address_2'],
                    'city'          => $user['town'],
                    'state'         => $user['county'],
                    'zip'           => $user['post_code'],
                    'country'       => $country['code'],
                    'email'         => $user['email'],
                    'first_name'    => $user['first_name'],
                    'last_name'     => $user['last_name']                   
                );


                // redirect client to PayPal
                echo $objPayPal->run($order['id']);



            }

        }

    }   

}
```

[IPN settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZDlG.jpg)
[IPN Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oClv.jpg)

Please help me with this .

Comment: You please send all information in the email on that page and check

Comment: i have sent everything to paypal ipn , i receive the ipn request in the return url (as shown in ipn history) but i cannot see anything on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPN is not related to your return URL.  If you're adding your code that you expect to run when IPNs are triggered to your return URL you will not get the expected result.

To get data to your return URL you would need to use PDT which is very similar to IPN but is intended to be sent to the return URL.  IPN goes to your notify URL, which should not match your return URL.